# Open email app screen when sending HTML email

Tags: javascript, html-email

Similar to `mailto:` keyword, I need to open (probably using Javascript) the email app (i.e. Outlook) with a predefined rich, HTML email allowing the user to edit it and send it out as any other email.

Is this possible?

Comment: try `window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here";`

Comment: I need an HTML in the body that the user can edit. The HTML will be already loaded when the user sees the email app window.

Comment: If you want to take input from user within web page then why you want to open third party email app ?

Comment: To reuse the contacts list in the mail app. The html is not a form, just text with images.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have access to the users' systems. You can't open specific apps or even know what they have installed. As far as I know, you can only have a the mailto link trigger the default mail client to open with predefined content for the to address, subject line and PLAIN TEXT BODY.

Comment: This is how I solved this: (1) I generated a request to the server, (2) I sent a server response in EML format with content-type: message/rfc822, (3) The EML format contains rich HTML including images, (4) the EML header has X-Unsent: 1 to open the email in edit mode, (5) the email is opened in the email app when the browser opens the file